# Unique Identity column across multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, database

Is it possible to get the Identity column value from some centralizes resource across multiple databases?

I'm interested especially in native MS SQL components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the Identity column value from some centralizes resource across multiple databases?

Identity is a table scoped object and you can't get that value across multiple databases

> I'm interested especially in native MS SQL components

From SqlServer 2012 ,you can use [Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) which are database scoped and you can call it from another database too..

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution in my case is [Linked Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx).

Comment: Your question asks about multiple databases and doesn't mention anything about multiple instances.